# Angularjs get data after add item with http post without refresh using mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

For add new user I use dialog using Angular Material (`mdDialog`), but now I must to refresh page to get new data added.

To get user I use this code in AdminController:

```
var init = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/getUsers'
    }).success(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            $scope.users.push(item);
        });
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
init();
```

To add a user I use this code in AdminController:

```
$scope.addUser = function(event) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/addUser.html',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        targetEvent: event
    }).then(function(addUser) {
        $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple()
                .textContent("User ajouté avec succès")
                .position('top right')
                .hideDelay(1500)
        );
    }, function(cancel) {
    });
};
```

And addUser I added this function in DialogController:

```
 $scope.addUser = function() {
    if($scope.password == $scope.cpassword) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/saveUser',
            data:  {email: $scope.email,password: $scope.password}
        }).success(function(data) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/assign-role',
                data: {email: $scope.email, name: $scope.selectedItem}
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.users.push(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log("password error");
    }

    $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I think because I put `$scope.users = []` in AdminController, and not have access in DialogController.

So how can I use `$scope.users` in both controllers?

Comment: the simplest way would be to keep users in rootScope as `$rootScope.users`. This way it will be accessible where you want it right now. However, this may not be a preferred way.

Comment: You can pass the users list to Dialog controllers using `locals` property of `$mdDialog`

Comment: The standard way however, would be to collect all such users to be added and then pass these along with `.hide`  add them in promise callback in your main controller

Comment: instead of  `$rootScope` i think you can use  `$emit` or  `$broadcast` to send a message to the parent controller so you array can be reloaded, or even use a  `$watch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of why to do it, like mention in comments  `$rootScope` or `locals` or  `$emit or $broadcast or $watch`

So i resolved with locals property of $mdDialog, so in $scope.addUser in AdminController  i do like this

```
 $scope.addUser = function (event) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            templateUrl: 'views/admin/addUser.html',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            locals: {
                    items: $scope.users
                },
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            targetEvent: event
        }).then(function (addUser) {

            $mdToast.show(
                $mdToast.simple()
                    .textContent("User ajouté avec succès")
                    .position('top right')
                    .hideDelay(1500)
            );
        }, function(cancel) {
        });
    };
```

and in add function

```
$scope.addUser = function () {
                if($scope.password == $scope.cpassword){
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/saveUser',
                        data:  {email: $scope.email,password: $scope.password}
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        $http({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/assign-role',
                            data: {email: $scope.email, name: $scope.selectedItem}
                        }).success(function (data) {
                            items.push(data);
                        });
                    });
                }
                else  {
                    console.log("password error");
                }

                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
```

and must the `items` pass in controller function .